# Retrive repository by entity type in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I'm writing Java program, which interacts with Db via Hibernate.

All my persistent classes extend from common abstract class `Entity` which implements interface `IEntity`. For example:

```
public interface IEntity {
    long getId();
    void setId(long id);
}

public abstract class Entity implements IEntity {
    private long id;
    //get + set id
}

public class User extends Entity {
    private string name;
    //get + set name
}

public class Item extends Entity {
    private string description;
    //get + set description
}
```

For operations with Db I created repository classes which extend from  `Repository<T extends IEntity>` with standard CRUD methods for all entities and this class implements interface `IRepository<T extends IEntity>`:

```
public interface IRepository<T extends IEntity> {
    void create(T object) throws JDBCException;
    //other CRUD operations
}

public abstract class Repository<T extends IEntity> implements IRepository<T> {
    private final Class<T> entityClass;
    protected final EntityManager entityManager;

    public Repository(Class<T> entityClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(T object) throws JDBCException {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(object);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    //other CRUD operations implementation
}

public class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
    public UserRepository (EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(AmountUnit.class, entityManager);
    }
}

public class ItemRepository extends Repository<Item> {
    public ItemRepository (EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(AmountUnit.class, entityManager);
    }
}
```

This structure worked well until I decided to create method to obtain specific repository by its entity class.
I see this method as something like this:

```
public <T extends IEntity, U extends IRepository<T>> U getByType(T object) {
        // code here
    }
```

Let's say, that class `User extends Entity` and have repository class `UserRepository extends Repository<User>`
I'm expecting, that this method should return Repository`for`User  object`.

From my point of view this can be achieved in two ways:

1. Elegant. Create method for `IRepository` - `Class<T> getEntityClass`
   and then compare classes of input and  result of getEntityClass
2. Stupid. Make many `if/else` statements inside this method and return repository. `if(object instanceof A) return ARepository`

   ```
   public class Storage {
        private IRepository<? extends IEntity>[] repositories;

        public <T extends IEntity, U extends IRepository<T>> U getByTypeVar1(T object) {
                    for (IRepository<?> repo : repositories) {
                        if (object instanceof repo.getEntityClass ()) // cannot resolve getEntityClass 
                        return repo;
                    }
                }

        public <T extends IEntity, U extends IRepository<T>> U getByTypeVar2(T object) {

                    if (object instanceof UserRepository.getEntityClass ())
                    return UserRepository; //incompatible type
                    //more if else here

                }
            }
   ```

But both of these implementation are failed to compile. May be you have any ideas how to write this method correctly

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code that doesn't compile. Do you use Spring, CDI or some other DI framework?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to add more details. PS. I do not use any IoC frameworks

Comment: I updated my answer with comments for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `getByType` method like this (I changed the parameter type):

```
private List<IRepository<? extends IEntity>> repositories;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E extends IEntity> IRepository<E> getByType(Class<E> entityClass) {
    for (IRepository<?> repository : repositories) {
        if (repository.getEntityClass().equals(entityClass)) {
            return (IRepository<E>) repository;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "No repository for entity class " + entityClass.getName());
}
```

When you post your code that failed to compile, we can figure out where the problem was.

**Update** (code comments)

You should add the `getEntityClass()` method to `IRepository`. 
To make the code less complicated, you can replace:

```
<T extends IEntity, U extends IRepository<T>> U getByType()
```

with

```
<T extends IEntity> IRepository<T> getByType getByType()
```

Using `instanceof` in

```
object instanceof repo.getEntityClass ()
```

can be problematic, since you can have entity hierarchies and you can get a wrong (subclass) repository for an object. If you don't know a class of the object, you can get it by (the object can be a Hibernate proxy):

```
org.hibernate.Hibernate.unproxy(object).getClass()
```

and then compare the classes by `repository.getEntityClass().equals(entityClass)`.

Comment: Do not know about this problem with `instanceof `. Solution works fine now. Thanks!